# While Loop Won't Exit While Using Read System Call

Tags: c, while-loop, system-calls

I'm working on building a basic program that acts as a shell using linux system call. Right now I'm trying to have it read the input in as a string so I can modify the information as needed. When I run the program and give it some input from the terminal it proceeds to hang afterwards. I'm guessing my while loop won't end, but I'm not sure why. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;

    char prompt[3] = "sh#";
    char input[256];
    char inputc;

    /*print out prompt */
    write(1, &prompt, sizeof(prompt));

    i = 0;
    while(read(0, &inputc, 1) != 0) {
        input[i] = inputc;
        i++;
    }
    input[i] = '\0';  /* null terminator */
    printf("%s\n", input);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to give the EOF character. Try entering your input then hitting ctrl-d.

Comment: This should be easy to debug. When you hook a debugger up to it and step through the code , does the second while loop break out ?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell

Comment: What exactly are you typing?  You tell `read()` to return `0` by indicating EOF with Control-D on most Linux systems, unless you change that key with `stty`.  Note that `read()` could return `-1` but your code would not spot that and would go into a tail spin until it crashed.  Since you aren't mentioning crash, it's reasonable to guess you hit 'return' but your program doesn't spot the newline and exit the loop; it looks for EOF (`read()` returning 0) only.  You could add a newline check and `break`.  (If you want to indicate EOF part way through a line of input, you type Control-D twice.)

Comment: `propmt` is too small, it should be `char promt[4] = "sh#"` because `"sh#"` needs 4 bytes including the `\0`.

Comment: @Pablo: since he's not using `printf` with it or treating as a string, `prompt` does not need to be NUL terminated.  Indeed, making it [4] would cause the`write` call to also write the NUL, which is undesirable.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, I understand that. What I don't know and I haven't tested it either, is whether the C compiler realizes that the buffer doesn't have enough space to hold the string and thus fills the buffer without causing a buffer overflow or it sees 4 bytes and fills them regardless of the size of the buffer. Is there something in the standard that deals with this?

Comment: @Pablo: see 6.7.8.14 of the C99 spec -- when initializing an array with a string literal, characters of the literal are used to initialize the array.  Remaining elements of the array will be initialized to 0.  So using `"sh#"` as an array initializer is equivalent to `{ 's', 'h', '#' }`, except if the size is unspecified it will get the size of the string including the NUL terminator.

Comment: @ChrisDodd ok, thanks. So that means that the assignment is not illegal, but you have to remember that you don't have a C-String (meaning that ends with a `\0`) anymore. I'm OK with that, with a short program like this you shouldn't have a problem with that, but I guess if the program is bigger you might run into problems. So to be 100% safe I still would use `char prompt[4]` or `prompt[]`.

Comment: the proposed code is using the signature for `main(), as if the parameters were going to be used.  In the posted code they are not used.  So the posted code should be using the `int main( void )` signature.

Comment: this line, which the compiler will not catch the error) does not allow enough room for the initialization string: `char prompt[3] = "sh#";`  It would be much better to let the compiler calculate the size needed by writing: `char prompt[] = "sh#";`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 3, 256.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names through out the code

Comment: the function: `read()` can return a -1, and the code will not catch that fact.  So the code has a logic error.  In general, it is always a good idea to check the returned values from both `write()` and `read()`

Comment: the `while()` code block and the following line that sets a NUL terminator would be much better written as: `if( fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin ) != NULL )`

Comment: @ChrisDodd, the `sizeof()` operator would not be the correct function to use if the NUL byte were allowed.  Suggest: `strlen()` which would still return 3, even though the total size of the array would be 4 bytes.

Comment: this statement: `char prompt[3] = "sh#";` actually results in undefined behavior.  Suggest: `char prompt[3] = {'s', 'h', '#'};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getline()` instead of `read()`.  Because `getline()` does a lot of the work for you.  Also, if you only wanted to receive 1 line from input, then simply use `read()` or `getline()` without the `while()` loop that you established.  The while loop will be most necessary for multiple inputs, which is what I assumed you wanted since you are calling this a shell type program and your prompt string has `sh` in it.

If you want to use `read()` in your code, then you should create your own `getline()` that uses `read()`.  This could be an example of the code for your own `my_getline()` function code for your loop using `read()`, and you should add your conditionals to break as you wish.

```
char *inputc, input[256];
int i;
for (i = 0; (read(STDIN_FILENO, inputc, 1) != EOF); i++)
{
    input[i] = inputc[0];
}
```

I have modified your code with this fix and removed the unneccessary variables.  You didn't use `argc` and `**argv` so they are removed as well.  The while loop uses `getline()` instead of `read()`.  The string is print after every input line.  The mini-shell terminates when the input string is: `"quit"`.  If you want to terminate with no input you can add a modification for this as well.

```
$ cat main.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 256;
    char prompt[5] = "sh$ ";
    char *inputc = NULL;
    /* print out prompt */
    write(1, &prompt, 4);
    while(getline(&inputc, &size, stdin) != -1)
    {
        /* check if input is "quit" to terminate the mini shell */
        if (strncmp(inputc, "quit", 4) == 0)
            break;
        /* prints the input */
        printf("%s", inputc);
        /* re-print out prompt to continue loop*/
        write(1, &prompt, 4);
    }
    printf("%s\n", inputc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output in your terminal (the third input is just newline `'\n'` or the [RTN] button, no input, and nothing is printed:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic main.c
$ ./a.out 
sh$ This is a test
This is a test
sh$ See how well getline works!
See how well getline works!
sh$ 

sh$ quit
quit


$
```